# How to allow PhotoSwipe to group images with varying structure into one viewable group

Tags: javascript, css, photoswipe

I'm using PhotoSwipe for an architectural blog.

My goal is to set up PS in such as a way that if the user taps any image in an entry, they can easily swipe to the next one. The issue is that the structure of my images displayed on the page (though each triggers PS currently and individually) are not set up using the below structure as prescribed by the PS documentation:

```
<div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

<figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
        <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <a href="large-image.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x400">
        <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
    </a>
    <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
</figure>

</div>
```

Mine looks like the below. All images are always displayed inside of `.wrapper` but `.wrapper` will have variable amounts of `.row` elements with a `div` then an `img`.

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row entry feed linked portrait">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <img class="featured image primary" src="_uploads/TheWhiteCave_10.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <img class="featured image secondary" src="_uploads/TheWhiteCave_1.png">
            <img class="featured image secondary" src="_uploads/TheWhiteCave_13.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The developer of PS, [said on Twitter](https://twitter.com/dimsemenov/status/542276576994664448) that I should look into `parseThumbnailElements' however after hours of trying, it's still totally unclear to me what I need to do.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but if somebody is trying to figure this out like me. I found this and it did the magic for me:
https://github.com/akizor/PhotoSwipe-Gallery-Improvement

All you need to do is include Photoswipe library, add a HTML tag that acts as a container for all your gallery images and use this javascript in your page.

I used div with a class **.images-container** as a container.

```js
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {
              var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
                var all = document.querySelectorAll(gallerySelector);
                var items = [];
                for(var j = 0 ; j < all.length; j++){
                  var el = all[j];
                  var thumbElements = el.parentNode.childNodes;
                  var numNodes = thumbElements.length,
                    figureEl,
                    linkEl,
                    size,
                    item;
                  for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                    figureEl = thumbElements[i];

                    if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    linkEl = figureEl.children[0];
                    size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');
                    item = {
                        src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                        h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
                        minZoom: 3
                    };
                    if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                        item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML;
                    }
                    if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                        item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
                    }

                    item.el = figureEl;
                    items.push(item);
                  }
                }
                return items;
              };
              var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
                return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
              };
              var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;
                var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
                  return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
                });
                if(!clickedListItem) {
                  return;
                }
                var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
                  childNodes = document.querySelectorAll(gallerySelector),
                  numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
                  nodeIndex = 0,
                  index;
                for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
                  if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) {
                    continue;
                  }
                  if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                    index = nodeIndex;
                    break;
                  }
                  nodeIndex++;
                }
                if(index >= 0) {
                  openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
                }
                return false;
              };
              var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
                var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
                params = {};
                if(hash.length < 5) {
                  return params;
                }
                var vars = hash.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                  if(!vars[i]) {
                    continue;
                  }
                  var pair = vars[i].split('=');
                  if(pair.length < 2) {
                    continue;
                  }
                  params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                }
                if(params.gid) {
                  params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
                }
                return params;
              };

              var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
                var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
                  gallery,
                  options,
                  items;
                items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);
                options = {
                  maxSpreadZoom: 5,
                  galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),
                  getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                    var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
                      pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                      rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect();
                    return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
                  },
                  minZoom: 3
                };
                if(fromURL) {
                  if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                      if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
                  }
                } else {
                  options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
                }
                if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
                  return;
                }
                if(disableAnimation) {
                  options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
                }
                gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
                return gallery.init();
              };
              var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );
              for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
                galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
                galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
              }
              var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
              if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
                openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
              }
            };

            // execute above function
            initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.images-container figure');
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the code that didn't work for you. All you need is:

- Query all elements that should open PhotoSwipe via something like [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll).
- Loop through each element and:

  - retrieve data for PhotoSwipe (large image size, dimensions) and push it in slides array,
  - set some attribute, like `data-index`, to image index in gallery,
  - bind click event.
- On click event open PhotoSwipe with slides array that you created, and on index from `data-index` attribute.